# Add a transparent black overlay using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a `background.mp4` video file that I'm using as the motion background on my website. However, the video is too bright and my site's text isn't easily readable.

How can I overlay a translucent black filter on my video using ffmpeg, so that my text is more easily readable?

Comment: Does it necessarily have to be a black overlay? It could also be a luminance curve or similar.

Comment: Perhaps a black, semi-transparent box behind white text could be another option. Can you provide the input file and/or a before and after mockup image so we know what you want to do? Also, the complete output of `ffmpeg -i background.mp4` would be helpful.